# How to use summernote in vue3 with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, summernote

Import vue3-summernote-editor is showing error.
Cannot find module 'vue3-summernote-editor' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

I have installed vue3-summernote-editor with npm install vue3-summernote-editor --save.
The package was installed successfully , however I'm unable to use it in any of my components.
I've checked my node_modules and the file is present in it.

These are the errors

'SummernoteEditor' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Cannot find module 'vue3-summernote-editor' or its corresponding type declarations.

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
  import SummernoteEditor from 'vue3-summernote-editor'; //ERROR IN THIS LINE

export default defineComponent({
    name: "surveytemplate",
    components: {},
    setup() {

        return {

        };
    },
});
</script>
```

// summernote source https://github.com/rafwell/vue3-summernote-editor

Comment: seems like summernote has no ts support. You can write //@ts-expect-error above the import.

Comment: Or try https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/summernote